# Firebird SQL Nested Select

Tags: sql, select, nested, firebird

I cant realize whats wrong with my query (Firebird SQL):

```
select max(column1) from (select first 100 column1 from table1 where column1 > 0) p
```

Error message:

```
SQL Message : -104
Invalid token
Message: isc_dsql_prepare failed
SQL Message : -104
Invalid token
Engine Code    : 335544569
Engine Message :
Dynamic SQL Error
SQL error code = -104
Token unknown
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

SQL does not have `FIRST` keyword it uses `TOP` keyword. Full explanation here

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx

Firebird:

"In MS SQL 7 and above, the SELECT clause can take a TOP specifier to limit the number of rows returned. This feature is currently under development for the Firebird engine."

http://www.firebirdsql.org/manual/migration-mssql-syntax.html#migration-mssql-sql-cursors

Comment: Database is not SQL Server, its firebird (as the title says)

Answer (score 3):

Nested SELECT queries ("SELECT from SELECT") use derived tables, which are only supported in [Firebird 2.0 and above](http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd20-select.html#langrefupd20-derived-tables).

However, since Firebird 1.5 allows SELECT statements to appear in the WHERE clause, your query can be rewritten as:

```
select max(column1) from table1
where column1 in (
    select first 100 column1 from table1
    where column1 > 0
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect SQL query, so it should work perfectly. I have tested something the same and it works. My guess is that the data type does not allow the comparison or max to be used. (e.g. column1 is a varchar or something non integer compatible)